# Toggle content with a div in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Seems simple, but I can't wrap my head around it. I am trying to toggle the content and have it show after clicking on the button div. I've tried writing a javascript function to toggle close and open but can't get it. Any help is appreciated.

```
            <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_toggle et_pb_toggle_close  et_pb_toggle_0 et_pb_toggle_item">
            <h5 class="et_pb_toggle_title">Content Button</h5>
            <div class="et_pb_toggle_content clearfix">
                <p> Content</p>

            </div> <!-- .et_pb_toggle_content -->
        </div> <!-- .et_pb_toggle -->
```

Comment: Please post your JavaScript attempt, otherwise it appears as if you're asking us to do all the work for you, which this site isn't about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function, like below :

```js
$('.et_pb_toggle_title').on("click",function(){
   $('.et_pb_toggle_content').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="et_pb_module et_pb_toggle et_pb_toggle_close  et_pb_toggle_0 et_pb_toggle_item">
  <h5 class="et_pb_toggle_title">Content Button</h5>
  <div style="display:none;" class="et_pb_toggle_content clearfix">
    <p> Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you'd like to start with the content hidden add inline `style="display:none;"` to the div with class `et_pb_toggle_content`

Answer (score 1):

So you need to have a click event, either inline (inside the tag of the element you want to click)

```
//Make a unhide function that sets the display to show, then call it using this
onclick="unhide();"
```

Or, in the JS file you can have an event listener such as follows.

```
document.getElementById("clickButton").addEventListener("click",function() {
    //Give the hidden element display:none; in the CSS
    document.getElementById("clickButton").style.display = inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using regular toggle, you can also use `fadeToggle()` to have it fade in and out, or `slideToggle()` to let it appear/disappear animated from/to the top.

```js
$('.et_pb_toggle_title').on("click", function() {
  $('.et_pb_toggle_content').fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
.et_pb_toggle_content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="et_pb_module et_pb_toggle et_pb_toggle_close  et_pb_toggle_0 et_pb_toggle_item">
  <h5 class="et_pb_toggle_title">Content Button</h5>
  <div class="et_pb_toggle_content clearfix">
    <p> Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```